# Does online play still work on Jump Force for PS4?

Tags: ps4, jump-force

I thought of purchasing Jump Force for PS4, it is not available on PS Store, and I don't know if I can still play it online using PS Plus if I purchase a physical copy. I heard the rumours that the online play will not work in year 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bandai Namco's [twitter](https://twitter.com/BandaiNamcoUS/status/1458298377385488391?s=20&t=g66BwZnKnh_FO_aHmAu4qQ) account, the online services were discontinued, and online gameplay can no longer be access as 08/24/2022 or 08/25/2022 (depending on your region). If you were to by a physical disk, the single-player mode can still be played

Comment: can't they just update the game and remove unlicensed manga characters to bring back game in market?

Comment: @SayedMohdAli That is a question for the developers, not Arqade. There might be more reasons than that

Comment: ok thanks for the information bro